# How is it possible to send json structured data via NFC?

Tags: android, nfc

I'm wondering if it is possible to send a json object, like [this](https://gist.github.com/kwylez/aafba134b267d91c211509f19aed7aba) for example, via NFC from a NFC device to an other NFC device?

I'm aware of, that there existed Android Beam in the past. But as far as I know, it used NFC just for the pairing and Bluetooth to transfer the particular documents. And it was only possible to transfer data between two Android devises.

But I'm searching for a possibility, which allows to data transfer only by NFC.

Answer (score 1):

Android Beam can send any data that is wrapped in an NDEF message, as the JSON is just text it can be easily wrapped in a standard NDEF text format or be given it's own custom mime type e.g. text/json

Android Beam has been depreciated in Android 10 and is only for Android to Android devices.

While Android Beam (Peer to Peer NFC) is being removed, it is still technically possible still to do transfer data use Host Card Emulation (HCE) on one Android Device and standard NFC reading on the other to simulate Android Beam (Though very advanced to do)

iOS devices have limited NFC capabilities and cannot do Android Beam and could only receive messages using the HCE from an Android Device using the method outlined above.

I suggest bluetooth or Wifi transfer as a better method.